# Storing MD5 Hash in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, md5

In SQL Server would a `varbinary(16)` be the most efficient way of storing an **MD5 hash**? Won't be doing anything with it except returning it in a **linq** query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) and my experience, binary is better, since the md5 hash does not vary in size.

The size for a binary data type is n bytes, so the size of the data.  The size of a varbinary data type is n bytes + 2 bytes on top of the size of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Null values change things:

A null varbinary(16) is 2 bytes. 
A null binary(16) is 16 bytes. 
16 bytes stored in varbinary(16) takes 18 bytes. 
16 bytes in binary(16) takes 16 bytes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731195