# Does "null" value in dataset occupy space?

Tags: dataset

ADO Dataset has ten fields in it. And the size of each field is 2 bytes.

If the dataset fields are filled with null values, will it still occupy the space of 2 bytes for each field, and 20 bytes of data is sent over the network?

Comment: What do you mean by "dataset"? There are many, many ways to represent data.  Please pick a specific one for your question.  XML, CSV, JSON all do this differently.  Also.  You **can** run experiments for your specific data representation.  Please run an actual experiment showing actual data you're actually working with and post that as part of your question.

Comment: Modified the dataset in question to ADO dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some space will be taken up. The amount depends on the actual database type you're using, and it's probably an implementation detail you shoudn't care about.

For example the `Firebird` database compresses all records when it writes them to disk. A raw of NULL's will probably take up less then a raw of 128 byte long strings. But it might take up the same amount of text as a raw of ZERO's.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Byers has an answer here for sql server:
[How much size "Null" value takes in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server)