# Does NULL occupy space on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server) and it has been confirmed that NULL does occupy space in sql server 2005. Has this changed in sql server 2012. Does NULL occupy space in sql server 2012?

Answer (score 4):

Still the same.

For fixed width fields like nullable int the storage space required is always the same regardless of whether the value is null or not.

For variable width nullable fields the value `NULL` takes zero bytes of storage space (ignoring the bit to store whether the value is null or not).

Answer (score 1):

It does.

If you don't want it to, declare the column as [`SPARSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx).