# Which is better for performance, make unused columns null or fill in with values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a `uniqueidentifier` column only used by some of the rows.

Is it a good idea  to:

- make that column nullable and make unused rows' uniqueidentifier null?
- or not make the column nullable and fill in a GUID value for all rows?

Will there be any performance difference with `SELECT` queries on the uniqueidentifier column? And what about disk space? Do null values take up the same amount of space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much size "Null" value takes in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server)

Comment: @littlebobbytables that answer didn't talk about uniqueidentifiers

Comment: Sorry, I was going off of the title of your question.  You've got like 5 questions here.

Comment: @James sure it does you just need to know if a GUID is fixed or variable. I'm pretty sure its fixed to 16 bytes

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Completely unrelated, but I love the name.  XKCD ftw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008+, you might want to look into using [sparse columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx). It is optimized for storing a column that contains mostly null values.

Answer (score 0):

Also check MSSQL filtered indexes if you are going to use nullable columns in where clauses.