# Why this new nullable TimeStamp field contains values after that I added to a table with pre existing records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following doubt. I am working with **Microsoft SQL Server** and I added a **TimeStamp** field named Data into a table specifying that this field is nullable. I added this new field to a table containing some pre existing records.

The problem is that querying my table:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[Numero protocollo]
      ,[Anno]
      ,[IdUor]
      ,[Protocollista]
      ,[Protocollato]
      ,[Lavorato]
      ,[Errore]
      ,[CopiaConoscenza]
      ,[Inoltro]
      ,[Data]
  FROM [IWG_PG].[dbo].[PROT_INOLTRO]
```

I am obtaining that these **Data** coulm contains values as **0x00000000000007F8**, **0x00000000000007F9**, etcetc

Why? I expected to find null. Why these records have a value for the **Data** field?

**EDIT-!**: This is the script:

```
USE [IWG_PG]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PROT_INOLTRO]    Script Date: 1/2/2019 4:54:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROT_INOLTRO](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Numero protocollo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Anno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdUor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Protocollista] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Protocollato] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Lavorato] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Errore] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CopiaConoscenza] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Inoltro] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [timestamp] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PROT_INOLTRO] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Numero protocollo] ASC,
    [Anno] ASC,
    [IdUor] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

As you can see the **Data** field is setted to **NULL**

Comment: Maybe your table has a Default value? Please, include the script that generates the table (created from SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42215930/1048425). Timestamp is a synonum, for RowVersion, which is not nullable (even if it is stated as such).

Comment: @GarethD More likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42215930, which shows NULL rowversion is possible.

Answer (score 3):

The `timestamp` data type is deprecated and also a synonym for the `rowversion` data type (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 for details). And `rowversion`contains the automatically generated binary numbers you're getting. Quote from the same page:

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime2 data type.

Maybe you just want to use a `datetime` column?

Answer (score 0):

This is legacy, and very arguably incorrect, behaviour.

SQL Server 2022 contains a feature to add a `NULL` `rowversion` for existing rows when a nullable `rowversion` column is added. This new metadata-only operation is not documented or publicly released yet. It is only accessible by enabling an undocumented trace flag.

This suggests the change is still being developed and/or fully tested. If it makes it into the final product, I expect it will be linked to database compatibility level or some other configuration option.

Answer (score -1):

You also shouldn´t use the name Data. This name could be reserved -->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Maybe this could cause some side effects

Comment: Same issues also changing name