# Handling Null using ConvertRecord in NiFi

Tags: mysql, apache, etl, apache-nifi

Is it possible to handle null (column does not exist in the CSV) using convertRecord or ant other processor?

I have several CSv files coming in daily. But the problem the fields are not same in each CSv, Is there a way I can send 0 value into the database for all those fields which doesn't exist in the CSV. If yes please let me no how? Thank you.

Ex: CSV1 has following field:
Age,Name,Address,Value1,Value2,**Value3**

(**Note:Value3 is not present in all CSV everytime, sometime it is present and sometime the column does not exist)**

CSV2 will have following:
Age,Name,Address,Value1,Value2

And in database The table skeleton is as follows:
**Age,Name,Address,Value1,Value2,Value3**

I don't want to have nulls followed by some value in the database. Is there a way my flow in NiFi can handle "null" and replace it with 0 before inserting into the database in an automated way (everytime if a specific field given in schema is not present in the CSV the flow should assign 0 to that field and ingest everything else in the database)

Please help me achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you have to **define avro schema with default values** in it.

**Sample avro schema:**

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "SQLSchema",
"fields" : [
{"name": "Age", "type": ["null","string"]},
{"name": "Name", "type": ["null","string"]},
{"name": "Address", "type": ["null","int"]},
{"name": "Value1", "type": ["null","int"]},
{"name": "Value2", "type": ["null","int"]},
{"name": "value3", "type": ["null","int"],"default": 0}
]
}
```

For `value3` field we have defined the type as `null (or) int` and **defined default value as 0.**

If there is **no data for value3** field then **it will replace the value as 0**.

Comment: Is there a way we can avoid entering that field into the database in order to store space.

Comment: @shrads,i'm not sure what do u mean by entering the field into database, As per the question my understanding is **you are thinking to replace null with some other default value**.If you don't want to occupy a space then use **null value** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server) but it depends on `data type` of the column also.