# Choosing best datatype for numeric column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sqldatatypes

I have a table in SQL Server with large amount of data - around 40 million rows. The base structure is like this:

| Title | type | length | Null distribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer-Id | number | 8 | 60% |
| Card-Serial | number | 5 | 70% |
| - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - |
| Note | string-unicode | 2000 | 40% |

Both numeric columns are filled by numbers with specific length.

I have no idea which data type to choose to have a database in the smallest size and having good performance by indexing the `customerId` column. Refer to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server) if I choose `CHAR(8)`, database consume 8 bytes per row even in null data.

I decided to use `INT` to reduce the database size and having good index, but null data will use 4 bytes per rows again. If I want to reduce this size, I can use `VARCHAR(8)`, but I don't know, the system has good performance on setting index on this type or not. The main question is reducing database size is important or having good index on numeric type.

Thanks.

Comment: As marc says below, the most important thing is choosing the correct datatype.

Comment: ***Never***, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns. Every time you do that a kitten dies (and never use `char` to begin with).

Comment: Have a look at sparse columns and page compression  @a_horse_with_no_name Correct re numbers, but `char` should be used when the length is fixed

Comment: @Charlieface If the numbers have a fixed length of 8, using `INT` is preferable.

Comment: @MohammadHajiHosseini Obviously if they are numbers, you should **never** store them as `char` as a_horse_with_no_name said. But if you have a fixed-length alphabetical **string** (ie it must be a certain length), then for sure use `char`, only use `varchar` when the length can be variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a **number** - then **by all means** choose a **numeric** datatype!! Don't store your numbers as `char(n)` or `varchar(n)` !! That'll just cause you immeasurable grief and headaches later on.

The choice is pretty clear:

- if you have **whole** numbers - use `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INT` or `BIGINT` - depending on the number range you need
- if you need **fractional** numbers - use `DECIMAL(p,s)` for the best and most robust behaviour (no rounding errors like `FLOAT` or `REAL`)

Picking the **most appropriate** datatype is much more important than any micro-optimization for storage. Even with 40 million rows - that's still not a big issue, whether you use 4 or 8 bytes. Whether you use a **numeric** type vs. a string type - that makes a **huge difference** in usability and handling of your database!

Comment: marc is totally correct, and fyi if your column has a large number of null values you can consider creating them as [SPARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) columns.

Comment: Suppose I have about eight columns in the database with the conditions specified. Again, you suggest using the same numeric type.

Comment: @MohammadHajiHosseini always use the **correct** type... else you will be dealing with technical debt for the life of the application. A large percentage of questions on this site are from people trying to handle the fact that they stored their data incorrectly.

Comment: But be very careful to make sure you're dealing with *numbers* and not "numbers". E.g. a Telephone Number is a "number" and *shouldn't* be stored in a numeric type, because leading zeros, non-digit characters may be important, and you don't do maths on them.